# Pandas groupby creating duplicate indices in Docker, but not on local

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have some code that works great on my machine, but not in Docker - probably because the version of pandas on my local is older than what I have in Docker.

Here is a snippet that will generate the code - Basically the snippet comparing two values, adding each row to a bucket based on the difference (e.g. over or under 10 % difference) and seeing the frequency of values in different buckets for different dates

```
def do_stuff(df):
    plotDf = df.loc[(df['a'].notna()) & (df['b'].notna()), ['a', 'b', 'removedDate']]
    plotDf.removedDate = plotDf.removedDate.dt.floor('D')
    plotDf['Change'] = (((plotDf['a'] - plotDf['b']) / plotDf['b']) * 100).astype(float).round(1)
    plotDf['Category'] = plotDf.Change.apply(lambda x: '> 10 % over' if x > 10 else ('5-10 % over' if x > 5 else ('0-5 % over' if x > 0 else ('net' if x == 0 else ('0-5 % under' if x > -5 else ('5-10 % under' if x > -10 else ('> 10 % under' if x <= -10 else None)))))))
    plotDf = plotDf[['removedDate', 'Category']].groupby(['removedDate', 'Category']).size()
    display(plotDf.head(5))
    plotDf = plotDf.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum())).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Share'})
    
    print(tabulate(plotDf.head(10), headers=['removedDate', 'Category', 'Share'],  tablefmt="psql"))
    
    plotDf = plotDf.pivot_table('Share', ['removedDate'], 'Category').fillna(0)
    display(plotDf.head(5))
    plotDf = plotDf.reindex(['> 10 % under', '5-10 % under', '0-5 % under', 'net', '0-5 % over', '5-10 % over', '> 10 % over'], axis=1)
    for col in plotDf.columns:
        plotDf[col] = plotDf[col].rolling(20, win_type='hann').mean()
    display(plotDf.head(25))
    plotDf = plotDf.reset_index()
    plotDf = plotDf.melt(id_vars=["removedDate"], var_name="Category",  value_name="Share")
plotDf.removedDate.fillna(pd.to_datetime('today')).dt.floor('D')
    <etc>
    
def random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = random.randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

import random
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d1 = datetime.strptime('1/10/2019 1:30 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
d2 = datetime.strptime('10/4/2023 4:50 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
dict_list = []
for i in range(0, 10000):
    a = random.randrange(100000, 400000, 250)
    b = a * (random.randrange(8, 13, 2) / 10)
    dict_list.append({'a': a, 'b': b, 'removedDate': random_date(d1, d2)})
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
do_stuff(df)
```

which can the be charted into something that looks like this (red means under 10 %, blue over 10 %)

[image]

In the above code, what I expect to see printed out at the part where I tabulate is this

```
+----+---------------------+--------------+----------+
|    | removedDate         | Category     |    Share |
|----+---------------------+--------------+----------|
|  0 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 | > 10 % under | 25       |
|  1 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 | net          | 75       |
|  2 | 2019-10-02 00:00:00 | > 10 % over  |  9.09091 |
|  3 | 2019-10-02 00:00:00 | > 10 % under | 36.3636  |
|  4 | 2019-10-02 00:00:00 | net          | 54.5455  |
|  5 | 2019-10-03 00:00:00 | > 10 % over  | 33.3333  |
|  6 | 2019-10-03 00:00:00 | > 10 % under | 66.6667  |
|  7 | 2019-10-04 00:00:00 | > 10 % over  | 25       |
|  8 | 2019-10-04 00:00:00 | > 10 % under | 50       |
|  9 | 2019-10-04 00:00:00 | net          | 25       |
+----+---------------------+--------------+----------+
```

What I get instead is an error `ValueError: cannot insert removedDate, already exists`
For some reason, this part of the code is creating a duplicate multi-index

```
plotDf = plotDf.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum()))<the rest>
```

and something that looks like this

```
removedDate  removedDate  Category
2019-03-18   2019-03-18   0-5 % under            100.0
2020-02-25   2020-02-25   net                    100.0
2020-04-09   2020-04-09   > 10 % over            100.0
2020-04-16   2020-04-16   0-5 % under            50.0
                          5-10 % over            50.0
dtype: float64
```

and since this is not a `pd.DataFrame` but rather a `pd.Series` with a multi-index that looks like `names=['removedDate', 'removedDate', 'Category']`, it obviously breaks at `.reset_index()` since there are two index columns with the exact same name.

I've no idea why `.groupby(level=0)` is doing this, but it seems like every operation I do to that dataframe after `.groupby(level=0)` will just duplicate the index.

I was able to fix it by adding `.groupby(level=plotDf.index.names).last()` which removes duplicate indices from a multi-level index, but I'd rather not have the duplicate indices to begin with.

```
plotDf = plotDf.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum())).groupby(level=plotDf.index.names).last().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Share'})
```